# Check if a node in a binary tree, is left of the root node

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, expression-trees

Given a binary tree, how can I identify if any node is a child of the left child of the node (or the left child of the node itself, but that part is fairly simple).

I'm working on an expression tree, and am trying to remove unnecessary parentheses from the expression when I do an inorder traversal of the tree. I've noticed that when the operator left of a node has the same priority as the node no parentheses are needed, but when to the right of the node parentheses are needed (unless the operators are both + or *).

```
public class ExpTree {
        private int type;
        private Object leafVal;
        private ExpTree lChild, rChild;
        public static final int NUM = 0, VAL = 1, OP = 2;

        public ExpTree(int type, Object leafVal, ExpTree l, ExpTree r) {
            this.type = type;
            this.leafVal = leafVal;
            this.lChild = l;
            this.rChild = r;
        }
}
```

I've thought about traversing the whole tree, but that seems like it would be inefficient.

Comment: Unless you have parent pointers, or something similar, you will have to traverse the whole subtree.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing parentheses in the expression tree. If you are not, I have no idea why you would need to look at anything other than the two child nodes to decide about parentheses. (Note: the parent prints the parentheses around the child. The child doesn't know if it needs to be parenthesized.)

Comment: @rici yeah I think I explained that badly, I'm not storing the parentheses in the tree, I'm trying to add them when I do an inorder traversal, but I'm trying to only add them when they're necessary, for example, if the original expression stored in the tree was something like ((a-3)-(b-5)) then my inorder traversal would return a-3-(b-5)

Comment: @chaz: right. But then `a-3` and `b-5` are direct children of the root `-` operation. So why do you need to look deeper in the tree?